# How do I pass a JSON attribute and display it within a template in an Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The following instance works but is really fickle

```js
angular.module('app', ['components']);
angular.module('components', [])
.directive("hbHero", function(){
    return {
        scope: {
          param: '='
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h1>{{param.h1}}</h1><h2>{{param.h2}}</h2><h3>{{param.h3}}</h3>'
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <hb-Hero param={h1:'Message1',h2:'Message2',h3:'Message3'}></hb-Hero>
  </body>
</html>
```

The second I add spaces to the HTML (as shown below) and re-run I am getting a parsing errors in the console.

```
<hb-Hero param={h1:'Message 1',h2:'Message 2',h3:'Message 3'}></hb-Hero>
```

What are some better options that would allow me to pass and access the JSON object within the attribute and display it within the template of the directive?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has a similar problem.

After tinkering with it a bit more it seems like it was a syntax problem. Upon adding double quotes as shown below the example worked with spaces added without modifying any of the javascript code.

```
<hb-Hero param="{h1:'Message 1',h2:'Message 2',h3:'Message 3'}"></hb-Hero>
```

I'm still interested in better ways to do this though this seems to get the job done.